# Files Could Not be Deleted Because They are Being Used by a Process

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I tried to execute the following command in PowerShell in order to remove a virtual machine together with its associated files.

```
Get-VM "VM Name" | %{
  Stop-VM -VM $_ -Force;
  Remove-VM -VM $_ -Force;
  Remove-Item -Path $_.Path -Recurse -Force
```

My problem, however, is that the script resulted to an error because some of the files (snapshots) were still being used by a different process. In addition to this, the **.vhdx** files were not deleted. Could anyone help me out how to solve this problem?

Comment: I guess you can try to terminate that other process. See [How to avoid Remove-Item PowerShell errors "process cannot access the file"?](http://serverfault.com/a/699945) or http://thomasardal.com/deleting-contents-of-a-folder-containing-files-with-open-file-handles-using-powershell/

Comment: So in this case, how will I be able to incorporate the script below to my script above?

`get-process | foreach{
        $pName = $_
        if ( $pName.Path -like ( $INSTALL_PATH + '*') ) {
            Stop-Process $pName.id -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
       Remove-Item  -Force -Recurse $INSTALL_PATH`

Comment: @wOxxOm Since in this case the other process is most likely the hypervisor I wouldn't recommend that. I suspect the issue is caused by snapshots being merged back into the image before deletion. Yes, it's pointless, but IIRC that's how Hyper-V handles these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (this needs to merge snapshots for VM , it needs sometime to complete the merging ):

```
Get-VM "VM Name" | %{Stop-VM -VM $_ -Force;Remove-VMSnapshot -vm $_;Remove-VM -VM $_ -Force;Remove-Item -Path $_.Path -Recurse -Force;}
```

Or (stop VMM service to remove VM files without merging):

```
Get-VM "VM Name" | %{Stop-VM -VM $_ -Force;Stop-Service -Name vmms -Force;Remove-Item -Path $_.Path -Recurse -Force;Start-Service -Name vmms ; start-service -Name vmhostagent;start-sleep 3;Remove-VM -VM $_ -Force}
```

In addition , my test lab is 2012R2 hyper-v host , please ensure that "path" folder doesn't contain other VM's file .

Comment: So this script will remove all the files in the specified path? What if all my VM's .vhdx files/snapshots are within the same folder? Will this script delete everything?

Comment: Yes.
I mean if  VM has its own folder to stored all its files .
If it doesn't fit your case , I will try to re-write it again .

Comment: No need, I found out that manually deleting the .vhdx files and snapshots is easier to do than executing a Powershell command. I will mark this as an answer nevertheless. Thank you!